# Sending files with Faye

Tags: ruby, form-data, faye

Is it possible to send files with Faye Ruby server?

Looks like FormData works only by XHR because e.g.:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', $('.file')[0].files[0]);

client.publish(channel, { file: fd });
```

returns an empty hash in my Ruby application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made using FileReader.

```
var sendMessage = function(file) {
  client.publish(channel, { file: file });
}

var fr = new FileReader();

fr.onload = function(event) {
  sendMessage(event.target.result);
};

fr.readAsDataURL($('.file')[0].files[0]);
```